# quiero realizar un grafico en cdplot para grupos de edad

Tags: rstudio

los grupos etarios son de "0-5", "5-9", "10-14", "15-19", "20-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-64", ">65" y lo que quiero graficas es una tabla de incidencia. Lo hice con grafico de lineas usando ggplot pero no quedo visualmente bien

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.